# powershell build-in function not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

*The term 'Write-Host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

*The term 'New-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again*

aka:Write-Host is build-in function in powershell. how to find root cause of that issue?

**Update**

[image]

**The same script works while executed in other dev machine.**

**update**

I have tried to set max memory of powershell for single instance to 1GB, and set max memory of powershell for single user to 100M. It still not work.

Comment: `> Write-Host hello world` it's working fine here. check your spelling and are you in powershell cmd

Comment: Seems like issues with powershell.exe without enough memory. it really work in my dev machine but not work in production env.

Comment: What's with all the powershell instances? Why do you need so many?

Comment: i use powershell in sqlserver agent job. so there are many sqlserver instance and many jobs run at the same time.

Comment: Just to make sure: if you open a powershell prompt on that machine and execute Write-Host, you get the error message? What do you get if you execute `gcm *host*`?

Comment: Any way, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is a limit on number shell instances that can be run by a single user. Are you hitting that limit?

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309367(VS.85).aspx

MaxShellsPerUser: The maximum number of shells per user. The default is 30.

Comment: Thanks vivek. it works after I remove some silos in our dev environment.

Comment: @suiwenfeng, could you please shed more light about how you resolve this problem as i run into the same issue. btw, I didn't see i hit the shell instance etc limits. Thanks !

Comment: @KenChen check all powershell processes and kill some of them, avoid over the limitation(MaxShellsPerUser);