# PowerShell, The term 'xxxxxx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

So i have the following PowerShell script that installs a third-party add-on in a program called M-Files.
This script worked perfect a couple days ago, then i tried to run it today without changing anything and it gave me a couple of errors as shown below.

I'm new to this so I did some research and did not find anything that helped..

**FYI:**
Tried to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847849/powershell-build-in-function-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet) solution and that did not help, I have no PowerShell processors running so I'm not hitting any limit.

Script:

```
# Application details
$appFilePath = "bin\Debug\ACV.mfappx"
$appGuid = "e9982d4b-e705-4016-a99c-dfd4bbe3fadc"

# Target vault
$vaultName = "IDIRMEGA"

# Connection details 
$authType = 1 # 1 = MFAuthTypeLoggedOnWindowsUser
$userName = ""
$password = ""
$domain = ""
$spn = ""
$protocolSequence = "ncacn_ip_tcp"
$networkAddress = "localhost"
$endpoint = 2266
$encryptedConnection = $false
$localComputerName = ""

Write-Host "Connecting to Vault..."

# Load M-Files API
$null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Interop.MFilesAPI")

# Connect to M-Files Server
$server = new-object MFilesAPI.MFilesServerApplicationClass
$tzi = new-object MFilesAPI.TimeZoneInformationClass
$tzi.LoadWithCurrentTimeZone()
$null = $server.ConnectAdministrativeEx( $tzi, $authType, $userName, $password, $domain, $spn, $protocolSequence, $networkAddress, $endpoint, $encryptedConnection, $localComputerName )

# Get the target vault
$vaultOnServer = $server.GetOnlineVaults().GetVaultByName( $vaultName )

# Login to vault
$vault = $vaultOnServer.LogIn()

# Try to uninstall existing application
try
{
    Write-Host "Checking for previous installation of ACV..."

    # Uninstall
    $vault.CustomApplicationManagementOperations.UninstallCustomApplication( $appGuid );

    Write-Host "Restarting after uninstall..."

    # Restart vault. The installation seems to fail, if the vault is not restarted after uninstall.
    $server.VaultManagementOperations.TakeVaultOffline( $vaultOnServer.GUID, $true )
    $server.VaultManagementOperations.BringVaultOnline( $vaultOnServer.GUID )

    # Login to vault again.
    $vault = $vaultOnServer.LogIn()
}
catch {}

Write-Host "Installing ACV..."

# Install application. The vault should not have the application installed at this point.
$vault.CustomApplicationManagementOperations.InstallCustomApplication( $appFilePath )

Write-Host "Restarting after install..."

# Restart vault
$server.VaultManagementOperations.TakeVaultOffline( $vaultOnServer.GUID, $true )
$server.VaultManagementOperations.BringVaultOnline( $vaultOnServer.GUID )
```

Error:

```
1>  Write-Host : The term 'Write-Host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable progra
1>  m. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:20 char:1
1>  + Write-Host "Connecting to Vault..."
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-Host:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
1>   
1>  new-object : The term 'new-object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable progra
1>  m. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:26 char:11
1>  + $server = new-object MFilesAPI.MFilesServerApplicationClass
1>  +           ~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (new-object:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
1>   
1>  new-object : The term 'new-object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable progra
1>  m. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:27 char:8
1>  + $tzi = new-object MFilesAPI.TimeZoneInformationClass
1>  +        ~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (new-object:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
1>   
1>  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:28 char:1
1>  + $tzi.LoadWithCurrentTimeZone()
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
1>   
1>  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:29 char:1
1>  + $null = $server.ConnectAdministrativeEx( $tzi, $authType, $userName,  ...
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
1>   
1>  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:32 char:1
1>  + $vaultOnServer = $server.GetOnlineVaults().GetVaultByName( $vaultName ...
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
1>   
1>  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:35 char:1
1>  + $vault = $vaultOnServer.LogIn()
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
1>   
1>  Write-Host : The term 'Write-Host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable progra
1>  m. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:56 char:1
1>  + Write-Host "Installing ACV..."
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-Host:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
1>   
1>  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:59 char:1
1>  + $vault.CustomApplicationManagementOperations.InstallCustomApplication ...
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
1>   
1>  Write-Host : The term 'Write-Host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable progra
1>  m. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:61 char:1
1>  + Write-Host "Restarting after install..."
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-Host:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
1>   
1>  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:64 char:1
1>  + $server.VaultManagementOperations.TakeVaultOffline( $vaultOnServer.GU ...
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
1>   
1>  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
1>  At C:\Users\Konica Minolta\source\repos\ACV\ACV\install-application.ps1:65 char:1
1>  + $server.VaultManagementOperations.BringVaultOnline( $vaultOnServer.GU ...
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
1>   
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: try open script at powershell ISE, then run some basic comands in CLI bottom of the window,like `Write-host "Hello world"` what happened?

Comment: I did that now, the first thing i saw when I opened PowerShell ISE is this error:

`The term 'set-variable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:0 char:0`

And Hello World error:

`Write-Host : The term 'Write-Host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2`

Comment: what is output at `Get-Command`? and check memory and processes powershell of any users.

Comment: Get-Command gave ma a long list of Cmdlets, Write-Host was not listed in them..

Comment: try to import module manually `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`

Comment: Do I run this in the PowerShell ISE?

Comment: better way add into script begining, and try what happens. You problem told that you not automatically load standart powershell modules.I can’t say why this happened, but to fix this it is enough to manually load the missing modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the best ussue of problem check path that contains modules:

1)Check `$env:psmodulePath` in powershell cli or ISE it's must contains path to directory with your modules (if it empty you must add path)

2)For manual loading modules that not finded/loading automatically use `Import-Module` cmdlet

3)You can config your psprofile  to load it [config_psprofile](https://msftplayground.com/2014/01/load-modules-by-default-when-openening-powershell/)